# Optimize row height/column width in Excel = minimize white space

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, table-styles

I often create tables in Excel where some cells contain a lot of text while others just contain a single digit or some other short value. With wrap text in cells enabled and then a combination of increasing row height and autofit the width of the columns there is a lot of wasted space in my sheets.

I would like a "smart" function that minimizes the unused white space. Does something like that exist? Or is there a algoritm that is simple enough to perform manually even on bigger sheets?

A few samples of what I mean:

A lot of wasted space horizontally

### [image]

Vertical wasted space

### [image]

This is probably pretty good

### [image]

With merged cells it is starting to get complex as seen in this and the next example

### [image]

Second example with merged cells

[image]

---

Thinking a bit more about this I have realised that the algoritm I am looking for can't be too naive and could/need different optimising strategies:

- Naive: In extreme cases it could end up making a cell with a lot of text very high, e.g., with just one letter or at least one word per line. Obviously that is not desirable.
- Usually I believe a squarish shape of the whole active area would be the most efficient. In that case optimising the circumference is probably the best strategy. However, if you want to print on a rectangular paper or view on a rectangular screen, it would make sense to sacrifice some optimisation to make sure that the data fits on one paper/screen.

Comment: Hmm, I added short descriptions to each image but they don't seem to be visible. However, they are there if I try to edit my question. Well well, the images should be pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Just figuring out how many lines wrapped text takes up is hard enough. I found [a method](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/394141-counting-lines-wrapped-cell.html) that turns off wrapped-text, checks the height, turns it back on, and checks the height again. You'd have to turn it off for all cells and check each cell individually. *THEN*, you'd have to adjust some columns and check each cell AGAIN. It could easily be a time-consuming optimization. I hope someone can think of a simpler way.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is going to be very similar to the calculus solution - you want the entire thing to look as close to a square as possible. Combine "Make it look like a square" with lastrow, lastcol, and resize, and I think that's the right track

Comment: What you are trying is practically not looking possible,, I mean to say any single method/Macro can't drive it. But one method you should try,, in MS-Word while making table height & width can be adjusted using `Fit to text` option,, so make Table and export to Excel !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VBA that takes the amount of chars in the cell, and use that number og ajust the column width.

Something like Max chars in column B -> Ajust column width to xx.